# Wiring a new light fixture

Tags: electrical

How do I wire a three way switch with power at the switch with 2 lights and a duplex receptacle that requires constant power.

Comment: 1 - What, if any, of these things (switches, receptacle, lights) currently exist? 2 - "power at the switch" - three way switches by definition have 2 switches, so which one has power? There are *many* ways to wire up three way switches, so a lot depends on the details. Draw (computer or hand-draw and take a picture) and upload a drawing showing: where power comes from (i.e., cable from panel) and where the switches, receptacle and lights are in relation to each other, along with the path the wiring will take. **Need more details.**

Answer (score -1):

Here is a diagram of a 3way set up.

[image]

Duplex receptacle would go in the same box as the incoming power. Or you need to run 12/ 4 cable to the other switch for a constant hot .